# Appropriately sorting and styling divs with css and html

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am trying to finish up my website design but I am having trouble displaying some divs and aligning them.

This is what I am trying to achieve:

[image: blivori.net mockup]

This is what I am getting:

[image: blivori.net actual]

[index.php](http://pastebin.com/pGGV454n)

[style.css](http://pastebin.com/iKTd0PGg)

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wMvL5/

content (the central div that contains the 'Latest Projects' and 'Latest News' divs:

```
<div class="content">

            <div class="projects">
                <h1>Latest Projects</h1>

                <div class="current_projects" align="center">

                    <div class="projects_gallery" align="center">
                        <table align="center">
                            <tr align="center">
                                <td>
                                    <div class="project_desc_1">Project Description 1</div>
                                    <div class="project_desc_2">Project Description 2</div>
                                    <div class="project_desc_3">Project Description 3</div>

                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr align="center">
                                <td>
                                    <div class="slide"><img src="./images/blivori.png"/ id="project1"></div>
                                    <div class="slide"><img src="./images/blivori.png"/ id="project2"></div>
                                    <div class="slide"><img src="./images/blivori.png"/ id="project3"></div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                <ol class='project_selector' align="center">
                                    <li></li>
                                    <li></li>
                                    <li></li>
                                </ol></td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr align="center">
                                <td>
                                    <label id="description1">Description 1</label>
                                    <label id="description2">Description 2</label>
                                    <label id="description3">Description 3</label>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>

                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="empty_div_two"></div>

            <div class="news">
                <h1>Latest News</h1>

                <div class="news_post" align="center">
                    <table align="center">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width: 5%">►</td>
                            <td style="width: 95%"><label class="newspost1">News 1</label></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>►</td>
                            <td><label class="newspost2">News 1</label></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>►</td>
                            <td><label class="newspost3">News 2</label></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>►</td>
                            <td><label class="newspost4">News 3</label></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>►</td>
                            <td><label class="newspost5">News 4</label></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>►</td>
                            <td><label class="newspost6">News 5</label></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>►</td>
                            <td><label class="newspost7">News 6</label></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>►</td>
                            <td><label class="newspost8">News 7</label></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>►</td>
                            <td><label class="newspost9">News 8</label></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>►</td>
                            <td><label class="newspost10">News 9</label></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>►</td>
                            <td><label class="newspost10">News 10</label></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>

            </div>
```

Mostly I am having trouble of displaying two divs (empty_div_two) which is found between 'Latest Projects' and 'Latest News' (the seperator) and '.misc' which is being displayed at all. I am also trying to put the 'Latest News' at the top right of the div. Also, the border-radius for the header doesn't seem to work.

Comment: If you give `.current_projects` a `margin-right`, that should take care of the need for the empty div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `border-radius` on your header, Apply it to your `.header-container` instead of `header`.

```
.header-container {
    border-top-left-radius: 30px;
    border-top-right-radius: 30px;
}
```

And to fix other things, do the following: **[SEE THE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wMvL5/3/)**

```
.empty_div_two {
    background: #fff;
}

.projects {
    float: left;
    width: 60%;
}

.news {
    width: 30%;
}

.current_projects // remove width: 49%;

.content // remove width: 1184px;
```

Comment: If you can upload JS fiddle or show me demo somewhere, I can help. But just sending codes via pastebin doesn't help.

Comment: Is that what exactly your site looks like? Because your screenshot and jsfiddle seems to have a lot of difference. Where is the space between your project and news like you have shown in the screenshot? Is there something you are missing?

Comment: Yes, the empty space is 'empty_div_two' which I added so as to have a vertical seperate between the 'current_projects' and 'news' divs within the 'content' div. Could it be it does not appear in jsFiddle to to the javascript code being jquery?